# Performance Benefits of Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, performance, lambda

I'm pretty new to lambda expressions in C# and I tend not to use them because I don't know what the benefits outside of minimizing code is. Are they more efficient in some/all cases? Or are there any fantastic things they can achieve beyond putting more code within one line?

Comment: Look at LINQ and deferred execution.

Comment: @SLaks Would you consider deferred execution directly related to lambdas?  I think of it as mainly a separate issue...

Comment: @Peter, good point. I meant than generic approaches to similar situations; not sure how to phrase that properly to be honest. I guess: "When are they efficient enough to justify their use based on performance?" may be better?

Comment: Lambda expressions are simply another syntax to write anonymous methods.  The compiler creates real methods and simply executes them.  From an execution standpoint they're not more efficient than writing your own method and creating a delegate to that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda expressions are not more performant, they are just simpler. They are mainly used for:

- Creating delegates
- Creating expressions for LINQ
- Putting local variables in captures for delegates

When creating a delegate, the code that the compiler creates is just like if you would have created a named method, and got a delegate to that method.

```
Func<int, int> mul = n => n * 2;
```

compared to:

```
public static int Mul(int n) {
  return n * 2;
}

Func<int, int> = Mul;
```

When creating an expression, the compiler creates an expression tree that can either be turned into a delegate or used by a LINQ provider to be translated into something else. The Linq To Sql provider for example would translate the expression into SQL code.

When creating a delegate that uses a local variable that is declared in the method that creates the deleage, a closure object is automatically created where that variable resides, instead of putting the variable on the stack. This is similar to how you would make the variable available to a named method by making it a field in the class where the method is declared.

```
int x = 2;
Func<int, int> mul = n => n * x;
```

compared to:

```
public class Closure {

  public int x;

  public int Mul(int n) {
    return n * x;
  }

}

Closure c = new Closure;
c.x = 2;

Func<int, int> mul = x.Mul;
```

Answer (score 10):

> Are they more efficient in some/all cases?

Lambda expressions, in general, aren't about performance efficiency as much as about developer efficiency.

They are a way to create methods in a far more productive manner than writing the methods by hand.  That being said, they do nothing to (directly) improve performance.

However, by properly utilizing frameworks which work in a functional manner (ie: using LINQ), you *can* increase your likelihood of writing efficient code, as the framework itself is likely highly optimized.